# How to persist data in Excel (VSTO) shared among few users?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have to load huge amount of data, pre-process it, share it among few users and finally gather updates back from users.

1. This is what I did in my previous project - 
   Created an excel add-in using C++. Loaded the data in memory using the add-in code and processed it. For each type of data I have sent the processed data to a sheet and saved a new excel file. That way, if I have three types of data, I have created three new excel workbooks. My users then opened those new workbooks, made their changes and dropped a text file that contains their changes (through a button). The main excel keeps polling for those updates (text files) and loads them as soon as they are found. That's the way I get the updates back from my users.
2. I am not a fan of what I did in my previous project, it produces too many temporary files (of course I can delete those). In my current project I want to use C# VSTO Workbook so I can have more control over excel. I was hoping once I load the data, I will ask my users to open the same excel in Read-Only mode and they will make changes. While testing this, I realized user's excel (opened in read-only) mode does not see the loaded data. And their changes do not update the data held in memory. This probably means I have no idea what I am doing.

Do you guys have any idea how to achieve this? I will really appreciate any help/hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel supports so-called "co-authoring" mode, when many people can edit the same document at the same time. But there is might be a catch: afaik, you need a Share Point/Office Online server/OneDrive Business to support this scenario (you need a non-free office document server product).

Using VSTO, you can do just the same you have done with C++ add-in, but in C# (means, the set of capabilities is 1:1 - it basically just wraps C++ COM Excel API for .NET)

But for online version of Excel, there may be yet another alternative - javascript addins (now that's called "Office Addins", afaik). But I doubt you'd want to process your "huge amounts of data" with javascript.

So I would say, there is a good rule: Don't fix something that isn't broken :)

If the problem is the number of temporary files, these files is not the only option to transfer data between applications. You know, you can connect two applications directly (so that they can exchange data with messages/updates). Use network, Luke :)

Of course if your 3 users live on 3 deserted islands, totally disconnected from anything, exchanging with text files on USB stick may still be the only viable option...

I think the "web" solution could be: store your file in some "co-authoring"-capable service (sharepoint, google shees, onedrive, officeonline, whatever). Make some web job to update that file in that storage automatically. Just like a "fourth" user would do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, Nikolay. I will try the share point route first, if that does not work for a reason then I will follow your advice "don't fix something that isn't broken" :)